# How do you set up Bootstrap button so that it becomes disabled in one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, twitter-bootstrap, button

The bootstrap button is to submit some data into the SQL server DB. I want the button to be disabled when the user clicks it once. But weirdly,
I have to click the button twice 'quickly' to make it disabled. But the onCommand c# function runs well no matter how you click it.
so here is the code

```
      <div style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:10px; text-align:center; "> 
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Ajax_SubmitReportRoom" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
          <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="SubmitReportRoom" type="button" CssClass="btn btn-info SubmitReport" OnClientClick="toggleVisibility();" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnCommand="SubmitReport_Command" CommandName="ReportRoom" CausesValidation="true" />
          </ContentTemplate>
          <Triggers>
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger  ControlID="SubmitReportRoom" />
          </Triggers>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
     </div>

     <script type="text/javascript">
     function toggleVisibility(){
         $('.SubmitReport').addClass('disabled');
         //$('.SubmitReport').attr("data-toggle", "modal"); // for some reason this is needed to disable the button but this causes OnCommand function to stop running
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function toggleVisibility(){
    $('.SubmitReport').addClass('disabled').attr("data-toggle", "modal");
}
```

Comment: Aww, now the OnCommand function doesn't work. I don't get why.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of addClass, try .attr('disabled', 'disabled')

Comment: I just tried it but same result. I just edited my question. The button is inside of updatePanel so it can trigger AJAX.

Comment: Maybe asp.net adding an event handler. Can you try adding a click event?  Hopefully you can preventDefault the click conditionally?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#SubmitReportRoom").on("click", function(){
    if (e.handled !== true) {
      e.handled = true;
      $("#SubmitReportRoom").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple code to disabled the button in this case call the toggleVisibility function on click event and process below code.

```
function toggleVisibility(){
    $('button').prop("disabled", true);
}
```